# How to I change syntax highlighting theme to "standard" for react

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

I am really struggling to find out how to set these colorization for syntax highlighting in Visual Studio Code and was hoping someone might know. As I have come to understand this is the "standard" for react.
i.e. green return statements, red jsx/html elements etc

[image]

This is a screenshot of my current text editor "font color theme" and the theme I am looking to change to.

The image as I said contains two sections,
The top section is how my VSCode looks right now
And the bottom section is how I want it to look.

I have looked for too many hours and I cannot figure it out.. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can look for a theme on visual studio marketplace if you haven't tried that already - https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode If you know the name of the theme you need, that might make finding the right extension easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can [customize your theme](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/themes#_customizing-a-color-theme). First open the [token inspector](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#scope-inspector) by executing the `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes` command from the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette):

[image: command palette]

It looks something like this:

[image: scope inspector]

You can then use the textmate scopes at the bottom of the window to change their look in your [JSON configuration](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "entity.name.function.ts",
            ],
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000",
            }
        },
    ],
}
```

The above code would change the color of typescript functions to red.

Use the scope inspector in your react file to find the token names for the type of word you want to change the style of. For each token add a `scope`/`settings` pair to the config.